# Ionic Cordova Build iOS Failed - Target overrides the LD_RUNPATH_SEARCH_PATHS in Pods

Tags: ios, xcode, cordova, ionic-framework, cocoapods

I'm trying to build an Ionic Cordova app to iOS and I'm having issues that seems related to Pods setup. I've tried to uninstall and install Cocoapods and Ionic platform/iOS several times.

This is the detailed error:

```
[!] The -[Debug] target overrides the LD_RUNPATH_SEARCH_PATHS build setting defined in `Pods/Target Support Files/---------/---------debug.xcconfig
```

I'm using following versions:
**Cordova: 11.0.0

Xcode: 13.2.1**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried in Xcode:

1. Target - > Building Settings- >LD_RUNPATH_SEARCH_PATHS,
2. Change the value to $(inherited)

That's what helped me making that error go away