# Cordova IOS 7 update and LD_RUNPATH_SEARCH_PATHS

Tags: ios, cordova, azure-devops

After updating to cordova-ios 7 I started to get this warning in cordova add platform. The command completes, but without installing the pods, which causes the process in cordova prepare ios to fail.

I found a possible solution here:
[Ionic Cordova Build iOS Failed - Target overrides the LD_RUNPATH_SEARCH_PATHS in Pods](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70650811/ionic-cordova-build-ios-failed-target-overrides-the-ld-runpath-search-paths-in)

The problem is that I don't have a machine with iOS and the build process is carried out with an **Azure Devops Pipeline**, i.e. **I can't change it in XCode because I don't have access to XCode at the time of the build**.

Here's the error message:
The `AppName [Release]` target overrides the `LD_RUNPATH_SEARCH_PATHS` build setting defined in `Pods/Target Support Files/Pods-AppName /Pods-AppName .release.xcconfig'. This can lead to problems with the CocoaPods installation

Comment: It's recommended to have a local IOS machine to validate the `possible` solution firstly. If it works, you can set the machine as `self-hosted` agent.

Comment: Even if I did, this is not an acceptable solution, since I need to make it work in the pipeline without a self-hosted machine.